# How to delete a folder in Android Studio emulator by using Android Device Manager?

Tags: android, directory, android-virtual-device

Android Device Manager's File Explorer lets me delete any number of files on AVDs but refuses to get rid of folders. Specifically, the minus sign icon whose hovering tooltip says "Delete the selection" stays grayed out no matter what I do. Short of writing an utility app I'm out of options :\ Any suggestions? A little nifty command-line wizardry, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to delete a folder in Android Studio emulator by using Android Device Manager?

That's not available, sorry. Ideally, it would be.

> A little nifty command-line wizardry, perhaps?

**`adb shell`** gives you a Linux shell onto the device or emulator, so...

```
adb shell rmdir /whatever/the/directory/path/is
```

would remove `/whatever/the/directory/path/is`. Note that the **`adb`** program is in your SDK's `platform-tools/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

When directory isn't empty and you want to rid off of all  of them

```
adb shell rm -r /whatever/the/directory/path/is
```